# Maps in Excel Power View

Tags: excel, bing, powerview

I have an analysis service implementation for my data in SQL SERVER 2012.
Now I want to create a geographic (map) report for my data in Excel power view reports.

When I add all my data in the report and click the map icon, it states that "The map background from bing is not available for this locale".

How to fix the bing issue.

Please help

Thanks
Prabhanjan

Comment: Hi Prabhanjan.  What are you using as the geographic values for your field?  City, Country, Latitude/Longitude etc?  It sounds like perhaps you have values in your geographic field that aren't being recognised as a valid location by Bing.

Comment: I was using latitude/longitude as geographic values

Comment: Okay, cool. If you're absolutely sure that your latitude/longitude values are valid, the only other thing I can think of is if perhaps you don't have an available internet connection through Excel to access Bing for the map. Is everything definitely enabled in Excel/Windows/firewall etc to allow access? As a test, you could just use some dummy values stored within the Excel file, and see if they work properly. That should narrow the issue down to either a problem with the connection to Bing, or your data.

Answer (score 1):

The Bing map control used by Power View isn't available for users in all [locals](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/maps-in-power-view-HA103005792.aspx). To get around this you need to change your computer's region settings to a supported region (not China or India).